# Cache flushing and cold caches

Tags: c, caching, x86-64

The code below showed up on one of the kernel mailing lists. I can't cite it at the moment because the message has not posted to any of the kernel archives (mail-archive.com, marc.info, or spinics.net):

```c
static void clflush(void)
{
    extern char const _init, _fini;
    char const *p = &_init;

    while (p < &_fini) {
        asm("clflush %0" : : "m" (*p));
        p += 64;
    }
}
```

Here's the description of the function from the message:

- Before every even-numbered iteration, I flushed the I-cache
  of everything from _init to _fini (i.e. all the non-library code).
  This cold-cache case is what is going to happen in the kernel.

I don't quite understand what is going on with the `_init` to `_fini` trick.

What is the purpose of the loop based on `_init`, `_fini` (and function pointers in between)? Why is a simple pointer that takes cache size and associativity not used?

---

Here's the full code provided in the message. The code attempts to benchmark a proposed algorithm (SipHash) with the cache in a certain state (cold) to avoid potentially skewed measurements.

```c
static void clflush(void)
{
        extern char const _init, _fini;
        char const *p = &_init;

        while (p < &_fini) {
                asm("clflush %0" : : "m" (*p));
                p += 64;
        }
}

typedef uint32_t cycles_t;
static cycles_t get_cycles(void)
{
        uint32_t eax, edx;
        asm volatile("rdtsc" : "=a" (eax), "=d" (edx));
        return eax;
}

static int benchmark(void)
{
        cycles_t start, finish;
        int i;
        u32 seq_number = 0;
        __be32 saddr6[4] = { 1, 4, 182, 393 }, daddr6[4] = { 9192, 18288, 2222222, 0xffffff10 };
        __be32 saddr4 = 28888, daddr4 = 182112;
        __be16 sport = 22, dport = 41992;
        u32 tsoff;
        cycles_t result[4];

        printf("seq num benchmark\n");

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                if ((i & 1) == 0)
                        clflush();

                start = get_cycles();
                seq_number += secure_tcpv6_sequence_number_md5(saddr6, daddr6, sport, dport, &tsoff);
                finish = get_cycles();
                result[0] = finish - start;

                start = get_cycles();
                seq_number += secure_tcp_sequence_number_md5(saddr4, daddr4, sport, dport, &tsoff);
                finish = get_cycles();
                result[1] = finish - start;

                start = get_cycles();
                seq_number += secure_tcpv6_sequence_number(saddr6, daddr6, sport, dport, &tsoff);
                finish = get_cycles();
                result[2] = finish - start;

                start = get_cycles();
                seq_number += secure_tcp_sequence_number(saddr4, daddr4, sport, dport, &tsoff);
                finish = get_cycles();
                result[3] = finish - start;

                printf("* Iteration %d results:\n", i);
                printf("secure_tcpv6_sequence_number_md5# cycles: %u\n", result[0]);
                printf("secure_tcp_sequence_number_md5# cycles: %u\n", result[1]);
                printf("secure_tcpv6_sequence_number_siphash# cycles: %u\n", result[2]);
                printf("secure_tcp_sequence_number_siphash# cycles: %u\n", result[3]);
                printf("benchmark result: %u\n", seq_number);
        }

        printf("benchmark result: %u\n", seq_number);
        return 0;
}
//device_initcall(benchmark);

int
main(void)
{
        memset(net_secret, 0xff, sizeof net_secret);
        memset(net_secret_md5, 0xff, sizeof net_secret_md5);
        return benchmark();

}
```

Comment: "What is the purpose of the loop" - clflush doesn't take a size, just a pointer.  It flushes the cache line that contains that pointer. "pointer that takes cache size" The code (apparently) already has the start and end pointers.  Why add an additional data item for the size?